# Header, main, footer stretch to fill page

Tags: jquery, css, html, positioning

I would like to have the following kind of HTML:

```
<header></header>
<div id='main'></div>
<footer></footer>
```

where all are preferably positioned relatively. The header and footer will have known height. I'd like the main div to, by default, fill up the entire page, with the header at the very top  of the page and the footer at the very bottom of the page.

Help?

Comment: Do you just want them to stretch to 100% width? Do you want the header and footer to stick at the top and bottom of the viewable page? We're sorta flying blind here.

Comment: I'm sorry for the ambiguity. I meant stretching 100% vertically, where header sticks to the top and footer sticks to the bottom

Comment: To the top and bottom of the viewable page, like one of those sticky side bars? Or just to the top and bottom of the page in general? Because if it's the latter then there's no extra code required. HTML doesn't create blank space unless you tell it to. In the other case, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using jquery:

```
$(function() {
     var height = $(window).height() - ($("header").outerHeight() + $("footer").outerHeight());
     $("#main").css("min-height",height+"px");
});
```

What we did basically is set the main div height to the browser viewport height and subtracted  the height of the header and the footer.

I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Rather than stretching your main to 90%, it's probably easier to just set

```
style='height:100%; margin-top=[header height]; margin-bottom=[footer height]'
```

since that'll keep your main a full page's length and not have the headers and footers overlapping content. Give it a try.

Comment: I'd like to ensure that the header, #main, and footer heights fill up 10% of the page vertically. so #main will need to stretch to fill probably 90% of the page vertically, but header and footer will have fixed heights.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the solution appears to be implementing

```
header {position: fixed;}

#main {min-height: 100%;}

footer {position: fixed;}
```

See a full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/J4jDu/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is one of my favorite solutions of all time.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Basically you have a wrapper that's 100% min-height, and from there you build the footer on the bottom, and header on the top, and the content in the middle will fill the rest.

```
#container {
   display:grid;
   grid-template-rows:auto 1fr auto;
   grid-template-columns:100%;

   /* fallback height */
   min-height:100vh;

   /* new small viewport height for modern browsers */
   min-height:100svh;
}
```